# When modifying a Rails app on Docker, how get source code changes to load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

When running a Rails app on a development machine, using Docker, how does once force code changes to be used?

I'm using Docker to test out / tweak a Rails app (Helpy), but when I modify the Rails source any changes just get ignored. Even changes to dockker/run.sh or tweaking text on a view.

So docker is apparently caching everything, how to I tell docker to use the current source code that I have edited?

I tried

```
docker-compose down (then up)
```

or

```
docker-compose restart
```

or

```
docker-compose build
```

The Dockerfile is

```
FROM ruby:2.4

ENV HELPY_VERSION=master \
    RAILS_ENV=production \
    HELPY_HOME=/helpy \
    HELPY_USER=helpyuser \
    HELPY_SLACK_INTEGRATION_ENABLED=true

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client imagemagick --no-install-recommends \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && useradd --no-create-home $HELPY_USER \
  && mkdir -p $HELPY_HOME \
  && chown -R $HELPY_USER:$HELPY_USER $HELPY_HOME /usr/local/lib/ruby /usr/local/bundle

WORKDIR $HELPY_HOME

USER $HELPY_USER

RUN git clone --branch $HELPY_VERSION --depth=1 https://github.com/helpyio/helpy.git .

# add the slack integration gem to the Gemfile if the HELPY_SLACK_INTEGRATION_ENABLED is true
# use `test` for sh compatibility, also use only one `=`. also for sh compatibility
RUN test "$HELPY_SLACK_INTEGRATION_ENABLED" = "true" && sed -i '128i\gem "helpy_slack", git: "https://github.com/helpyio/helpy_slack.git", branch: "master"' $HELPY_HOME/Gemfile

RUN bundle install

RUN touch /helpy/log/production.log && chmod 0664 /helpy/log/production.log

# Due to a weird issue with one of the gems, execute this permissions change:
RUN chmod +r /usr/local/bundle/gems/griddler-mandrill-1.1.3/lib/griddler/mandrill/adapter.rb

# manually create the /helpy/public/assets folder and give the helpy user rights to it
# this ensures that helpy can write precompiled assets to it
RUN mkdir -p $HELPY_HOME/public/assets && chown $HELPY_USER $HELPY_HOME/public/assets

VOLUME $HELPY_HOME/public

COPY docker/database.yml $HELPY_HOME/config/database.yml
COPY docker/run.sh $HELPY_HOME/run.sh

CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '2'

services:
  frontend:
    image: webwurst/caddy
    volumes:
      - ./docker/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - ./certs:/etc/caddy/certs
    volumes_from:
      - helpy:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - front
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - helpy
  helpy:
    image: helpy/helpy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    volumes:
      - rails-assets:/helpy/public
    env_file: docker/.env
    #environment:
    #  - DO_NOT_PREPARE=true
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back
    env_file: docker/.env
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  rails-assets:
    driver: local

networks:
  front:
    driver: bridge
  back:
    driver: bridge
```

In docker-compose.yml I changed

```
  helpy:
    image: helpy/helpy
```

to

```
  helpy:
    build: .
```

expecting that to stop using the pre-built docker image, and use the code on the development machine. But any changes I make to a view (for example just changing some heading text on a view from "Admin Brand" to "My New Header") get ignored. I tried

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

Similarly I tried docker-compose build or docker-compose restart

So Docker is apparently caching the source, not using the "live" version of the source that I edit.

I've used Vagrant quite a lot but am very new to Docker so any help on modifying a Docker project to allow local development changes would be appreciated.

Comment: Your source code is in a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) right ? If not, you should look at it...

Comment: Can you show the  `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use:

```
volumes:
  rails-assets:
    driver: local
```

You tell to docker create a volume and put your data inside.

But if you want to share your local code in real-time sync with the container, you need to do that:

```
helpy:
    image: helpy/helpy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    volumes:
      - ./local/path/to/your/code:/helpy/public
```

Now when you change your local code, simultaneously the code will change inside the container.